# How can I detect when a user enters or leaves a game and get the game name they entered/left?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Discord.js has a `presenceUpdate` event with `oldPresence` and `newPresence` objects. Various posts I've seen here and elsewhere say to use these to detect when a user enters/leaves a game and what game it is, but v14 `presenceUpdate` objects don't make this information clear.

I've sort of gotten around this, but my solution isn't stable or reliable. The `oldPresence` object has a `frozenPresence` property which will list a game if the user was playing it in the `oldPresence`. The `newPresence` object has a map of all presences on the guild, so I can find the user the presence applies to with their `userID` and find the game listed in that presence.

But sometimes `presenceUpdate` fires when a user hasn't left or entered a game, so this results in funky behavior and sometimes crashes. Actual code below. Welcome any suggestions.

```
discordClient.on("presenceUpdate", (oldMember, newMember) => {
    let user = oldMember.user.username;
    let userID = newMember.user.id

    if(oldMember.frozenPresence.game != null && newMember.frozenPresence == null) {
        if(oldMember.frozenPresence.game.name != null) {
            let game = oldMember.frozenPresence.game.name;
            sendGroupMeMessage(user + " has stopped playing " + game, () => {});
        }
    }
    else {
        newMember.guild.presences.forEach((value, key) => {
        if (key == userID) {
            sendGroupMeMessage(user + " is playing " + value.game.name, () => {});
        }
    });
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm just gonna put this out there but if your guild even only has 100 people this will be really slow.

Comment: It has 4 and it's not gonna get bigger, but if you have ways to optimize, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 0):

The newer version of `discord.js` takes `Presence` as arguments in [`presence update`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/Client?scrollTo=e-presenceUpdate) event, but you were using GuildMember type which is incorrect.

The following function does -

- Verify if the `oldPresence` was undefined and if the number of new activities is more than the number of old activities - if so then probably that user joined the game
- Verify if the `newPresence` was undefined and if the number of old activities is more than the number of new activities - if so then probably that user left the game

```
async onPresenceUpdate(oldPresence, newPresence) {
    const oldActivitiesCount = oldPresence.activities.filter(
      (x) => x.type === ActivityType.Playing
    ).length;
    const newActivitiesCount = newPresence.activities.filter(
      (x) => x.type === ActivityType.Playing
    ).length;
    // Enter new game
    if (
      (!oldPresence && newPresence) ||
      newActivitiesCount > oldActivitiesCount
    ) {
      const newUserActivity = newPresence.activities
        .filter((x) => x.type === ActivityType.Playing)
        .at(0);
      if (newUserActivity) {
        console.log('New game:' + newUserActivity.name);
      }
    }
    // Leave game
    else if (
      (oldPresence && !newPresence) ||
      newActivitiesCount < oldActivitiesCount
    ) {
      const oldUserActivity = oldPresence.activities
        .filter((x) => x.type === ActivityType.Playing)
        .at(0);
      if (oldUserActivity) {
        console.log('Leave game:' + oldUserActivity.name);
      }
    }
  }
```

Possible improves:

- Save in key value pairs the id and the name of the game and then be sure that the user left the correct game